# How inefficient is my ray-box-intersection algorithm?

Tags: c++, 3d, hlsl, raycasting, intersection

One of the most critical parts of my raytracer is the calculation of a collision between ray-box which is done following way:

```
inline bool hitsCube(in Ray ray,            in Cube cube, 
                     out float tMin,        out float tMax,
                     out float3 signMin,    out float3 signMax)
{
    float3 biggerThan0 = ray.odir > 0; // ray.odir = (1.0/ray.dir)
    float3 lessThan0 = 1.0f - biggerThan0;
    
    float3 tMinXYZ = cube.center + biggerThan0 * cube.minSize + lessThan0 * cube.maxSize;
    float3 tMaxXZY = cube.center + biggerThan0 * cube.maxSize + lessThan0 * cube.minSize;
    
    float3 rMinXYZ = (tMinXYZ - ray.origin) * ray.odir;
    float3 rMaxXYZ = (tMaxXZY - ray.origin) * ray.odir;
    
    float minV = max(rMinXYZ.x, max(rMinXYZ.y, rMinXYZ.z));
    float maxV = min(rMaxXYZ.x, min(rMaxXYZ.y, rMaxXYZ.z));
    
    tMin = minV;
    tMax = maxV;
    
    signMin = (rMinXYZ == minV) * lessThan0; // important calculation, but no context provided here
    signMax = (rMaxXYZ == maxV) * lessThan0;
    
    return maxV > minV * (minV + maxV >= 0) // last multiplication makes sure the origin of the ray is outside the cube;
}
```

This function is called inside a hlsl-shader many many times (for some pixels at least 200/300 times), but at some points lags occur. Is my implementation of the collision logic inefficient?
'I tried to avoid branches as much as I can, thus, in return having more multiplications.